# How do I make a member of a class a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, class, hash, object

I am trying to write a package in perl. I need one of the members to be a hash. However, when I reference and run the program, I cannot get it to work with the usual syntax. If I have:

```
sub new
{
my $class = shift;
my $self = {
    textfile => shift,
    placeholders => ()
};
bless $self, $class;
return $self;
}
```

Is there any way of making "placeholders" a hash I can access via $self->{placeholders} ?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574744.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, but you have to make it a *hash reference*.

```
$self = {
   textfile => shift,
   placeholders => { }         #  { }, not ( )
};
...


$self->{placeholders}->{$key} = $value;
delete $self->{placeholders}->{$key};
@keys = keys %{$self->{placeholders}};
foreach my ($k,$v) each %{$self->{placeholders}} { ... }
...
```

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much! I suppose I should have figured that out. Thanks again!

Comment: Feel free to accept mobrule's answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: Too many right answers here. Shows what we are all doing at the end of the day... :)

Answer (score 6):

All members of aggregates (arrays, hashes, and objects that are arrays are hashes) are scalars. That means that an item in a hash is never another array or hash, but it can be an array or hash *reference*.

You want to do (to a first approximation):

```
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my ($textfile) = @_;
  my $self = {
    textfile => $textfile,
    placeholder => {},
  };
  return bless $self, $class;
}
```

And then when you use it (assuming that you also have a `placeholder` accessor), you can use `$obj->placeholder->{key}`, `%{ $obj->placeholder }`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

`()` constructs an empty list.  This is fine when you are assigning to a `%hash` but otherwise, Perl just treats it as an empty list which is merged into the surrounding list.  Just as you did when you assigned to `$self`, you need to use the curly braces `{ }` to construct an anonymous hash reference.

Answer (score 4):

You want a hash reference. Use curly braces instead of parentheses:

```
sub new { 
     my $class = shift; 
     bless { textfile => shift, placeholders => {} }, $class; 
     }
```